# Method that returns file size and possibly file type

Tags: python-3.x, pyrogram

Is there any method to return the size of a file and possibly file type in Pyrogram (not Python itself)?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used python in a while but I think you can use the os module for this.

```
import os
size = os.path.getsize('path/to/file')
print(size)
```

Comment: yeah but I didn't mean size on a physical disk, I mean size in telegram messages

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   if message.document:
                name = message.document.file_name
                file_size = message.document.file_size
                file_type = message.document.mime_type
                f_id = message.document.file_id
    elif message.video:
                name = message.video.file_name
                file_size = message.video.file_size
                file_type = message.video.mime_type
                f_id = message.video.file_id
```

same goes with photo